# How to insert data into different tables based on drop down list?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a form that can accept two types of users. The different user types are provided in a select tag. I need to insert data into two separate tables based on the user's selection. With my current code I'm not able to insert data into either table. Most of the form inputs are common in both tables. I also need the 'required' attribute in all input fields.

This is the image of the form:

[image: This is the image of the form]

This is the HTML:

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post">

  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" required autocomplete="off" />
  </div>                   
                    
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>Email Address<span class="req">*</span></label>
     <input type="email" name="email" required autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
                    
  <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>Phone Number<span class="req">*</span></label>
     <input type="tel" name="phone_no" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label>Set A Password<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off" />
  </div>                   

<!--For selecting the type of user-->
                  
                    
  <div class="field-wrap combo">
                      
    <label>Account Type</label>
                              
    <select class="AccountType" id="account_type" name="account_type">
      <option value="AT" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Account Type</option>
      <option value="User">User</option>
      <option value="Agent">Agent</option>               
    </select>                   
 
  </div>
                  
<!--These are the options available only for agents-->
  <div id="agent_options">
                        
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>Agency Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="agency_name" <?php echo $required ?> autocomplete="off" />
    </div>        
                        
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>Street Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="street_name" <?php echo $required ?> autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
                        
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>City<span class="req">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="city" <?php echo $required ?> autocomplete="off" />
     </div>
                        
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <label>State<span class="req">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="state" <?php echo $required ?> autocomplete="off" />
    </div>                     
                        
  </div>                   
                    
  <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>

</form>
```

This is the PHP code I have used.

```
 if(isset($_POST['register']))   
{

    if(isset($_POST['account_type']))
      {

        $account_type=$_POST['account_type']; 

        if($account_type=="Agent")
                    $required="required"; 
        else    
                    $required="";
        }


    if($account_type=="User")
    {
        $user_name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone_no=$_POST['phone_no'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $query="INSERT INTO user_details (user_name,email,phone_no,password) VALUES ('$user_name','$email','$phone_no','$password')";

        mysqli_query($connection,$query);   
    }
    else
    {
        $user_name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone_no=$_POST['phone_no'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $agency_name_name=$_POST['agency_name'];
        $street_name=$_POST['street_name'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $state=$_POST['state'];

        $query="INSERT INTO agent_details (agent_name,email,phone_no,password,agency_name,street_name,city,state) VALUES ('$user_name','$email','$phone_no','$password','$agency_name','$street_name','$city','$state')";

        mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two tables in the first place?

Comment: What error do you get? Also you could have one table with `type` field which would be 'user' or 'agent' based on your account type

Comment: I would also suggest to follow [PSR-2 coding style](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: Have a look in your error log and see if you get any SQL related errors.  Also worth seeing what value $_POST['account_type'] actually is, you can use something like this `error_log('account_type: ' . $_POST['account_type']);`  to print this value to the error log .  You could also error log the statement itself `error_log('myQuery: ' . $query;` to the error log and see if that shows any obvious errors.  Not related to your question but something you should take a look at is sanitizing your input against SQL Injection.